# Avoid string field cloning in rust

Tags: rust, clone, allocation, serde

I've `MyObjManager` that holds an array of `MyObj` (more than 1500 elements). `MyObj` has a lot of `String` fields and an option integer.

The `serialize` function takes a manager and a price for serializing the array with the new price.

Something like this:

```rust
use serde::{Serialize};
use serde_json;

#[derive(Serialize, Clone)]
pub struct MyObj {
    id: String,
    name: String,
    price: Option<u32>
}

pub struct MyObjManager {
    my_objs: Vec<MyObj>
}

fn get (manager: &MyObjManager, price: u32) -> Vec<MyObj> {
    manager.my_objs.iter()
        .map(|my_obj| {
            MyObj {
                price: Some(price),
                ..my_obj.clone() // string allocation
            }
        })
        .collect()
}

pub fn serialize (manager: &MyObjManager, price: u32) -> String {
    let my_objs = get(manager, price);
    serde_json::to_string(&my_objs).unwrap()
}
```

With this implementation, every `serialize` call allocates a lot of string. It's possible to avoid that?

NB: the array of `MyObj` can be consider static and doesn't change in the time

Comment: if id and name are immutable, you could consider to change their type to `Rc<str>`. You easily get an `Rc<str>` from a `&str` or a `String` and `clone` only copies a pointer and increases the reference counter (instead of allocating a new string).